# Cannot get Android lay-out correctly? Relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-imageview

### Help me with the lay-out!

I'm making an Android app which has a swipe fragment screen. Below is the view for the fragment.

### The problem

For some reason, the image is great on top. But, I need to scroll in order to get to the text! It's put on layout_below imageview though!

Check out these screenshots:

1) http://tinyurl.com/km52n2a

2) http://tinyurl.com/netaffa

You might think it's because of the scrollview, but I tried removing it and it didn't change anything except for the ability to scroll..

### It gets more weird

I've used this code in an older app and it worked perfectly (and I just tested it again, works smooth!). I copy pasted it into my new app and now the text is being very annoying.

### I've tried many possibilities. Please help me out here!

### Some code explanation

**intro_btnSkip:** A button shown on the last fragment to go to the next activity.

**imageview:** the image to show on top

**textview:** the description to show below the imageview

---

### The code!

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".IntroActivity$MyFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/intro_btnSkip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/btnIntroSkip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/introDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewFragment"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13sp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/icoon_app" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: it's not necessary to shout out "help me" all the time. People already know you have a problem, that's why you post the question. I can't answer your question, just suggesting you to remove the "help me"

Comment: and you might try to move the imageview above the textview in the xml, the creation of the layout is linear.

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content" try to change to android:layout_height="fill_parent" in the relativelayout

Comment: Its your background image, you have a large background image which is causing the text to go at the bottom, just remove the background image and check if the issue still persists !

Comment: Sadly, I don't have a background image. I've tried all of your suggestions but none (neither combined) seem to work :(.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look it is very similar to your code, it works very well here, Have you considered that might be your img, the problem??

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".IntroActivity$MyFragment" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/intro_btnSkip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/introDescription"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:text="button"
            android:visibility="visible" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/introDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewFragment"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="13sp"
            android:text="KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: And this fixes a bug in your xml, the button could stay behind the text.

Comment: I just did this, and I've got a huge scrollbar, my image sitting in the middle of it and the text with a huge gap between the image and text. The image is 272x408 and works in my other app, don't see what could be wrong..

Comment: weird I tried with the same image size and it works pretty fine,don't know what could be wrong too sry..